# Joomla router problems

Tags: php, url, joomla, router

I had a code that works for addsmanager component but they make some changes and now doesn't work anymore.

Old code is this:

```
function getAdsmanagerRouteContent($id)
{
    $db =JFactory::getDBO();
    $sql = "SELECT category,ad_manufacturers,ad_modelauto,ad_jetmodels,ad_model FROM #__adsmanager_ads WHERE id = ".(int)$id;
    $db->setQuery($sql);
    $result = $db->loadObject();
        $url = TText::_($result->ad_manufacturers);
        if ($result->ad_modelauto != "")  {
            $url .= "-".TText::_($result->ad_modelauto );
        }
        if ($result->ad_jetmodels != "")  {
            $url .= "-".TText::_($result->ad_jetmodels );
        }
        if ($result->ad_model != "")  {
            $url .= "-".TText::_($result->ad_model );
        }

    $url = TTools::stringURLSafe($url );
    $url = JString::substr($url ,0,30);
    return $url ;
}
```

They have this code now

```
function getAdsmanagerRouteContent($id)
{
    $db =JFactory::getDBO();
    $sql = "SELECT ad_headline FROM #__adsmanager_ads WHERE id = ".(int)$id;
    $db->setQuery($sql);
    $result = $db->loadResult();
    $result= TTools::stringURLSafe($result);
    $result = JString::substr($result,0,30);
    return $result;
}
```

which I have modified like this

```
function getAdsmanagerRouteModel($id)
{
    $db =JFactory::getDBO();
    $sql = "SELECT ad_model,ad_motomodel FROM #__adsmanager_ads WHERE id = ".(int)$id;
    $db->setQuery($sql);
    $result = $db->loadResult();
        if ($result->ad_model != "")  {
            $result .= "-".TText::_($result->ad_model );
        }
        if ($result->ad_motomodel != "")  {
            $result .= "-".TText::_($result->ad_motomodel );
        }   
    $result= TTools::stringURLSafe($result);
    $result = JString::substr($result,0,30);
    return $result;
}
```

The ad_model is loaded but if instead ad_model is ad_motomodel this isn't loaded.
Is a way to make this code work? I am not such good at PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was originally written to work with two different variables ($result and $url) but uses one instead.

```
$result = $db->loadResult();
if ($result->ad_model != "")  {
    $result .= "-".TText::_($result->ad_model );
}
```

Once the thrid line gets executed, you now don't have the object `$result` anymore. It is gone. You now have a string `$result` containing whatever the "stringification" of your previous object yields (an empty string in this case) plus a dash and the contents of `ad_model`. After that, you cannot access `$result->ad_motomodel` anymore.

What you *really* want is something like this:

```
$db =JFactory::getDBO();
$sql = "SELECT ad_model,ad_motomodel FROM #__adsmanager_ads WHERE id = ".(int)$id;
$db->setQuery($sql);
$result = $db->loadResult();
$url="";
if ($result->ad_model != "")  {
    $url .= "-".TText::_($result->ad_model );
}
if ($result->ad_motomodel != "")  {
    $url .= "-".TText::_($result->ad_motomodel );
}   
$url = TTools::stringURLSafe($url);
$url = JString::substr($url,0,30);
return $url;
```